# Optimize this code for large input

Tags: c#, optimization

i have this solution that works for smaller inputs say an input string of length up to 350,beyond that it gives runtime error.input constraint is    0 < input<500 .

this problem is from https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/quantium/challenges/k-mismatch

how can i optimize this code to handle strings up to length 500?

Language c#

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  class Solution {
static int mismatch(string a, string b)
    {
        int result = 0;    
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
           if (a[i] != b[i])
               result++;
        return result;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long no = 0;
        int K = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string word = Console.ReadLine();
        List<string> wordList = new List<string>();
        List<string> curr = new List<string>();

        var query =
             from i in Enumerable.Range(0, word.Length)
             from j in Enumerable.Range(0, word.Length - i + 1)
             where j >= 1
             select word.Substring(i, j);


        for (int i = 1; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (string s in query) { if (s.ToString().Length == i)curr.Add(s);  }
            if (curr.Count() > 1) 
                for (int j = 0; j < curr.Count(); j++)
                    for (int k = j + 1; k < curr.Count(); k++)
                        if (mismatch(curr.ElementAt(j).ToString(),      curr.ElementAt(k).ToString()) <= K)
                        no++;
                curr.Clear();

        }
Console.WriteLine(word.Length+":"+no);

    }
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think SO likes "review my code for me" questions because it is tailored to _your_ code, and is unlikely to help others in the future. You might find more luck at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but looking into a suffix tree might help? [k match with suffix tree](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.1406.pdf) ior [this](http://www.rosshemsley.co.uk/tag/k-mismatches/)

Comment: What runtime error does it give?

Answer (score 2):

The main limiting factor that I see here is the fact that you're computing every single substring for a particular string, and then materializing that *entire query* into a list (with the line `query.ToList();`).  That will consume a *lot* of memory for a non-trivially sized string.  Not converting that to a list and instead foreach-ing over the query itself will allow you to stream that information, thus dramatically reducing your memory footprint.  Since you iterate it for each letter though, not materializing it means computing each of those values N times, which will slow the program down.  Since you don't *have* enough memory you have no choice but to live with that slowdown though (unless you can improve the underlying algorithm to not need to perform such a large and complex query so many times).

Comment: removing query.toList(); helped get rid of runtime error still hitting time limits.

Comment: @Rakon_188 Well of course you are.  The general algorithm that you're using is absurd with respect to its asymptotic complexity.  Like, completely absurd.  If you want it to not be really, really slow for non-trivially sized inputs then try to find a better algorithm to accomplish your goal.  Your algorithm is something like O(N^7), by the looks of it.

Comment: how would you approach this problem?just an insight would be great

Comment: @Rakon_188 In this case you're trying to solve a problem for a contest.  The whole *point* of the contest is that it's inherently hard to come up with an algorithm that can solve the problem efficiently.  Looking at what you have, my guess is you're not really on the right track at all.  You're brute forcing the problem, and chances are the constraints are such that that is intentionally not an option.  Start over and find a cleverer approach to the problem.